# How to convert a vertical string in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

```
d = {'Banana' : {'price': 7, 'Color' : "yellow"},
'Apple' : {'price' : 8, 'Color': "green"}, 'Orange' :{'price' : 6, 'Color': "orange"}}
for fruit, props in dict.iteritems():
    prices= str(props['price']):
```

Now I want to have the price of each fruit in a list

`print prices
6
7
8`

 But if I use split(), I get:
`print prices.split()
['6']
['7']
['8']` 
And what I really want is `[6,7,8]`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post what the raw string actually looks like for instance does `string.split('\n')` work?

Comment: @EdChum I added my raw string, split('\n') or splitlines() don't give the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). From the documentation:

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.

You can use it like this:

```
>>> mystring = """1
2
3"""
>>> mylist = mystring.splitlines()
>>> print(mylist)
['1', '2', '3']
```

And since you want the lines as integers:

```
>>> mylist = [int(i) for i in mystring.splitlines()]
>>> print(mylist)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Keep in mind that you'll get an error if any line is *not* a integer or float.

## EDIT (after the post revision):

It seems like your main problem is the `for` loop. You are setting `prices` on each iteration, overwriting the last. You should use something like this:

```
prices = []
for fruit, props in d.iteritems():
    prices.append(props['price'])
```

Then you have a list, looking like this:

```
[8, 6, 7]
```

Notice it has no order. This is because [dictionaries are unstructured data types](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). From the docs:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

If you want, you could sort your prices:

#### Least to Greatest

```
>>> sorted(prices)
[6, 7, 8]
```

#### Greatest to Least

```
>>> sorted(prices, reverse=True)
[8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every run of the for-loop will wipe out the previous value of `prices`. So you either need to build a list or print out the prices immediately. To print them immediately, prevent `print` for appending a newline by adding a comma:

```
for fruit, props in dict.iteritems():
    price= str(props['price'])
    print price ,
```

You'll get something like

```
6 7 8
```